# Can someone please explain this line

Tags: c, arduino

```
K_count = (K_count < (byte)(CharacterMask[0][(customKey - '0') - 1][0]) ? ++K_count : 1);
```

It is a part of [this](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/CellPhoneKeypad) simple code,  and i cant understand how precisely does it work?

Comment: Note: `++K_count` should be `K_count +1` [sequence points]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this basically increments through the available options on a standard US telephone keypad for the "3" key, looping back to the first option after the last is reached.  it does so by referencing a 3-dimensional array containing the options for each key layed out as row/column/options. it is written in such a way that it can be reused for other keys with minor modifications.

the "...?...:..." construct is basically a shortcut for if/else. so you can rewrite the statement like this:

```
if (K_count < (byte)(CharacterMask[0][(customKey - '0') - 1][0])) {
    K_count = ++K_count;
} else {
    K_count = 1;
}
```

the "++" operator simply adds 1 to the variable, so you can rewrite as:

```
if (K_count < (byte)(CharacterMask[0][(customKey - '0') - 1][0])) {
    K_count = K_count + 1;
} else {
    K_count = 1;
}
```

CharacterMask is a 3-dimensional array that describes a typical telephone keypad. the first 2 dimensionsindicate the row and column of the keypad. the third dimension contains the options available on that key. so, for example, the 3 key on a telephone has 4 options (3,d,e, and f). for some reason, the author also includes the option count as the first item in the array (index 0).  so CharacterMask[0][2] would give you an array containing the number 4 followed by the characters '3','d','e', and 'f'. as such, CharacterMask[0][2][0] will return the number 4. similarly CharacterMask[0][2][1] would return the char '3'. since this line of code is only really concerned with the number of options, not their values, the final array index is hard-coded to 0. given that, you can rewrite the code like this to clarify:

```
rowIndex = 0;
columnIndex = (customKey - '0') - 1;
optionCountIndex = 0;
if (K_count < (byte)(CharacterMask[rowIndex][columnIndex][optionCountIndex])) {
    K_count = K_count + 1;
} else {
    K_count = 1;
}
```

since customKey is a char and not a number, we can use the "-" operator to subtract the '0' char. this implicitly casts both values to a byte and returns the difference between those bytes.  since the numbers are ordered 0-9 in most character sets, this effectively gets us the numerical value of the character stored in the customKey variable (e.g. char 3 becomes byte 3). so the code can be rewritten as follows:

```
rowIndex = 0;
keyNumber = (customKey - '0');
columnIndex = keyNumber - 1;
optionCountIndex = 0;
if (K_count < (byte)(CharacterMask[rowIndex][columnIndex][optionCountIndex])) {
    K_count = K_count + 1;
} else {
    K_count = 1;
}
```

since they keys 1,2,3 are found in columns 0,1,2 in a zero-based indexed column count, we need to subtract 1 from the keyNumber to get the column index as shown above

because CharacterMask is a char array, we need to cast the first value to a byte to get the value initially entered back. this rewrite clarifies that:

```
rowIndex = 0;
keyNumber = (customKey - '0');
columnIndex = keyNumber - 1;
optionCountIndex = 0;
optionCountAsCharType = (CharacterMask[rowIndex][columnIndex][optionCountIndex]);
if (K_count < (byte)optionCountAsCharType) {
    K_count = K_count + 1;
} else {
    K_count = 1;
}
```

the comparison with K_count relies on the fact that the option array length is equal to the option count plus 1. since it is zero-based indexed, that means the last index is equal to the option count. so as long as the current K_count (aka option index) is less than the option count, you can still add 1 without exceeding the max index value. but if you are on the last index, you must roll back to 1 (the index of the first option). it could be made more clear with one more refactor:

```
rowIndex = 0;
keyNumber = (customKey - '0');
columnIndex = keyNumber - 1;
optionCountIndex = 0;
optionCountAsCharType = (CharacterMask[rowIndex][columnIndex][optionCountIndex]);
nextIndexIsInsideArrayBounds = K_count < (byte)optionCountAsCharType
if (nextIndexIsInsideArrayBounds) {
    K_count = K_count + 1;
} else {
    K_count = 1;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for the effort, great explanation!

Answer (score 1):

You can expand that single line of code to:

```
int temp = (byte)(CharacterMask[0][(customKey - '0') - 1][0]);
if ( K_count < temp )
{
   K_count = ++K_count;
   // This is bad. See the comment about sequence points.
   // It should be
   K_count = K_count + 1;
}
else
{
   K_count = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> (customKey - '0') - 1
> ```

This takes the value of `customKey`, subtracts the ASCII value of "0" (0x30), and then subtracts 1 from that.

> ```
> CharacterMask[0][x][0]
> ```

This takes the 0th element of `CharacterMask`, takes the `x`th element of the result, and then takes the 0th element of *that* result.

> ```
> (byte)x
> ```

This truncates `x` to its 8 least significant bits.

> ```
> K_count < x
> ```

This is true (i.e. non-zero) if `K_count` is less than `x`.

> ```
> x ? y : z;
> ```

This results in `y` if x is true, otherwise it results in `z`.

As to what it actually *does*, that depends on what `CharacterMask` and `customKey` are.